# Has the minimum reputation for commenting been changed?

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation

A user with 6 reputation (at the time of writing it) made [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668861/same-class-in-class-nested#comment96128000_54668861). How is that possible?

They later added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54669134/1663001) as a reply to me which has pushed their rep even lower still. Am I missing something? As far as I am aware, the [minimum reputation required to comment is 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

I can't see anything in their public profile that indicates they had more than that at any point and I believe an answer converted to a comment should still leave a residual deleted post (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570635/1663001) - 10k only)?

Comment: It's not his question, either...

Comment: An answer converted to comment? They do have another poor quality answer on the same question

Comment: That'd be possible.

Comment: @yivi But we should see that as a deleted answer right (like the one I link at the end of my question)? I realise you can't see it, so here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PDoa.png).

Comment: The minimum repo for comments has not been changed. It's more likely that what changed is what happens with answers converted to comments. Or that not all answers coverted to comments are shown the same way.

Comment: It's an automatic comment conversion, where an attempt at using an answer is turned into a comment instead. There is no answer to delete in such cases. This kicks in if the answer is short and links to another post on the site.

Comment: Ahaaaa, that makes sense. I thought I was missing something, thanks @Martijn.